# How is this function continuous, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = x-1$ when $x\in(1,2]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How is this function continuous, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = x-1$ when $x\in(1,2]$? I see that $f(x) = x-1$ is continuous on that interval because for all $a\in(1,2]$ the limit as $x\rightarrow a = f(a)$. However I am not sure how to work out the limit at $x=0$.

EDIT: The domain of $f$ is $\{0\} \cup (1,2]$

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? $\{0\}\cup(1,2]$?

Comment: Do you mean $f(1)=0$ where you have $f(0)=0$?

Comment: Yes it is, I''l edit the post

Comment: No, $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: This $f$ is even Lipschitz-continuous. Given $\epsilon>0$ you can always let $\delta=\epsilon$ ...

Comment: Hint: $\{0\}$ is open in $\{0\}\cup (1,2]$. This leads to simple characterization of sequences in $\{0\}\cup (1,2]$ that converge to $0$. You can calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ easily from there.

Answer (score 0):

Since 0 is an isolated point in the domain, it can't be approached and so $f$ is continuously by default.

Answer (score 0):

For every $\epsilon$ $\gneq$ $0$, choose $\delta =1/2$. Then note that the point $x\in E$ ($E$ is the domain of the function) such that $\mid x-0\mid\lneq$ $1/2$ is the only point $x=0$. Hence clearly $\mid f(x)\mid\lneq\epsilon$. So, f is continuous.

Comment: @ Ken Levasseur It can be approached only by the constant sequence: 0,0,0,.....(no offense :D)